# Razor variable in jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, variables, razor

I want to make:

```
@{
 var myVariable = "GenericId" + UniqueId;
}
```

And use the `myVariable` as a jQuery selector :

```
$('#@myVariable').doSomething();
```

but it doesn't work.

It that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use parenthesis to create an explicit expression and tell Razor you want it to interpret that as code:

```
$('#@(myVariable)').doSomething();
```